# How do I rotate labels in a plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Consider the following plot:

```
Show[LogLogPlot[{x, x^2, x^1.5, 5/x}, {x, 0.5, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 3}, {0.5, 10}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25],
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, 
     Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Blue, 
     Dashing[0.02]}, {Thick, Darker@Darker@Green, Dashing[0.02]}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{Style["Curve 1", 21], Style["Curve 2", 21], 
     Style["Curve 3", 21]}, {0.83, 0.15}], 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{4}, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
    4 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
    5 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}}], 
 Graphics[{Text[Style["Domain 1", 20, Darker@Blue], 
    Scaled[{0.3, 0.5}]], 
   Text[Style["Domain 2", 22, Darker@Blue], Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]]}]]
```

The result is

[image]

Could you please tell me how to rotate the legend "Domain 2" to make it collinear to the blue line?

P.S. Without the deformation of the text.

Comment: `Rotate[Text[Style["Domain 2", 22, Darker@Blue], 
  Scaled[{0.45, 0.8}]], -45 Degree]`

Comment: @BobHanlon : unfortunately the rotated text is deformed (this seems to be due to LogLog scaling).

Comment: how about `Text[Style["Domain 2", 22, Darker@Blue], 
 Scaled[{0.5, 0.75}], Left, {3, -1}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You can use the fourth argument of `Text` to control the direction of text:

```
LogLogPlot[{x, x^2, x^1.5, 5/x}, {x, 0.5, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 3}, {0.5, 10}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick,Red}, {Thick, Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thick, Blue}},
 ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style["Curve 1", 21], Style["Curve 2", 21], 
    Style["Curve 3", 21]}, {0.83, 0.15}], 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{4}, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
   4 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["Domain 1", 20, Darker@Blue], Scaled[{0.3, 0.5}]], 
   Text[Style["Domain 2", 22, Darker@Blue], Scaled[{0.5, 0.75}], Center, {3, -1}]}]
```

[image]

**2.** You can have the text orientation determined by the curve it is associated with  using a custom arrowhead:

```
LogLogPlot[{x, x^2, x^1.5, 5/x}, {x, 0.5, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 3}, {0.5, 10}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
  BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[0], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Darker @ Darker @ Green}, 
     {Thick, Blue, Arrowheads[{{Automatic, .5, 
       Graphics[Text[Style["Domain 2", 22, Darker@Blue], {0, 0}, {0, -1}]]}}]}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style["Curve 1", 21], Style["Curve 2", 21], 
     Style["Curve 3", 21]}, {0.83, 0.15}], 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{4}, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
    4 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["Domain 1", 20, Darker@Blue], Scaled[{0.3, 0.5}]]}] /. 
  Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
LogLogPlot[{x, x^2, x^1.5, 5/x}, {x, 0.5, 3},
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 3}, {0.5, 10}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25],
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Thick, Blue},
   {Thick, Red},
   {Thick, Darker@Darker@Green},
   {Thick, Blue},
   {Thick, Blue, Dashing[0.02]},
   {Thick, Darker@Darker@Green, Dashing[0.02]}},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style["Curve 1", 21], Style["Curve 2", 21],
    Style["Curve 3", 21]}, {0.83, 0.15}],
 Filling -> {1 -> {{4}, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.1]]},
   4 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]},
   5 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}},
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["Domain 1", 20, Darker@Blue], 
    Scaled[{0.3, 0.5}]],
   Inset[
    Graphics[
     Rotate[
      Text[Style["Domain 2", 22, Darker@Blue], Scaled[{0.45, 0.8}]],
      -20 Degree]],
    Scaled[{0.5, 0.6}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In case you are not aware, it is possible to interactively edit the plot output which is often the fastest way for a one-off solution.

If you hover over "Domain 2" in the output and double click you should see an editing frame:

[image]

Use the handles to rotate and position the label:

[image]

Then click outside the graphic and the edit is saved:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how to pull the “`FullForm`” of the resulting figure when one makes modifications in this manner?

Comment: @CATrevillian You can wrap the resulting graphic object in `FullForm` (or `InputForm`) and evaluate the cell; `Graphics` is handled as a normal expression since *Mathematica* version 6.0.